# alcance variable globales dentro de una promesa

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Tengo este fragmento de código en node.js, similar javascript, bueno lo que pasa es que use métodos asíncronos para realizar una validación de campos que se ingresa por medio un archivo csv, por lo tanto debo analizar valor por valor de del arreglo `_data`, tengo ademas en objeto `user` donde contiene las propiedad de `user` como variable global.
El problema se encuentra cuando quiero cambiar los atributos de estas propiedades dentro de métodos me dan error de **undefined** en cuando hago uso de `this`.

¿Cómo debería de usar promise?.

```
 this.user = {
                nombre: "",
                descripcion: "",
                email: "",
                fotografia: "",
            },

            isEmpty: function (str) {
                return (!str || 0 === str.length);
            },
            getUrlPath: function (fotografia) {
                return firebaseApp.database().ref("user").orderByChild("fotografia").equalTo(fotografia).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                    this.user.fotografia = snapshot.fotografia; **//error, undefined**
                        console.log(" su correo es " + snapshot.val().email);
                    // salida su correo es 'nombre@gmail.com'
                });
            },

            //devuelve un correo desde firebase
            _getEmail: function (_email) {
                // var result = false;
                return firebaseApp.database().ref("user").orderByChild("email").equalTo(_email).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                    this.user.email = snapshot.email; **//error, undefined**
                        console.log(" su correo es " + snapshot.val().email);
                    // salida su correo es 'nombre@gmail.com'
                });
                // return result;
            };
            validar: function (_data) {
                var partialErrors = "";
                var that = this;
                //fotografia
                this.getEmail(_data[3])).then(function (_valid) { **//aca funciona el this**
                      if (!_valid) {
                        partialErrors = partialErrors + "'" + _data[3] + "'" + " url no valida | ";

                    }

                    // nombre
                }).then(function (value) {
                    if (this._isEmpty(_data[1])) { **//error, undefined**                        
                        partialErrors = partialErrors + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " valor incorrecto | ";
                    }
                })
            //descripcion
            .then(function (value) {
                if (this._isEmpty(_data[2])) { **//error, undefined**                        
                    partialErrors = partialErrors + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " valor incorrecto | ";
                }
                //email
            }).then(function (value) {
                //obligue que ingresara aunque sea valida
                if (this._getEmail(_data[2])) { **//error, undefined**
                    console.log("valor :  " + this.user.email);  **//error, undefined**
                        partialErrors = partialErrors + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " es incorrecto, sólo válido <email@domain.com> | ";
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            if (partialErrors.length > 0) {
                //error, undefined** No funciona el this
                this.errorFields.push("En " + _data + " se econtro errores en " + partialErrors);
                console.log(this.errorFields);
            }

            }
```

Comment: Crea los setters una opción la otra es usar el método bind pero la primera opción que te doy es lo más fácil y lo comprenderás más rápido

Comment: Donde this funciona es porque this apunta al objeto que continene la funciones, donde falla es porque el contexto ha cambiado  (lo llamas dentro de las promesas...)y this ya no es el objeto que continene la funciones: la sulucion es fácil: crear una variable global que apunte a this, eso ya lo hiciste al poner var that=this; (pero no las haz usado); luego solo llamas a todas las funciones desde that, por ejemplo that._isEmpty(...)